# Global variable defined in Content Provider and initialized in onCreate() is null in query()

Tags: android, global-variables

I defined a content provider and made my database helper a global variable, which I initialize in the onCreate method. However, the value of this global variable is null, in the query() method.

This is my content provider:

```
    /** Tag for the log messages */
    public static final String LOG_TAG = FeedingProvider.class.getSimpleName();

    // Declaring a FeedingDbHelper variable;
    private FeedingDbHelper mDbHelper;

    /** URI matcher code for the content URI for the pets table */
    private static final int FEEDINGS = 100;

    /** URI matcher code for the content URI for a single pet in the pets table */
    private static final int FEEDING_ID = 101;

    /**
     * UriMatcher object to match a content URI to a corresponding code.
     * The input passed into the constructor represents the code to return for the root URI.
     */
    private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

    // Static initializer. This is run the first time anything is called from this class.
    static {
        // The calls to addURI() go here, for all of the content URI patterns that the provider
        // should recognize. All paths added to the UriMatcher have a corresponding code to return
        // when a match is found.
        sUriMatcher.addURI(FeedingContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, FeedingContract.PATH_FEEDINGS,
                FEEDINGS);
        sUriMatcher.addURI(FeedingContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, FeedingContract.PATH_FEEDINGS +
                "/#", FEEDING_ID);
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the provider and the database helper object.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {

        mDbHelper = new FeedingDbHelper(this.getContext());
        // Make sure the variable is a global variable, so it can be referenced from other
        // ContentProvider methods.
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
                                    String sortOrder) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Test in query: " + (mDbHelper == null));

        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor;

        int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);

        switch (match) {
            case FEEDINGS:
                cursor = db.query(FeedingContract.FeedingEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection,
                        selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
                break;
            case FEEDING_ID:
                selection = FeedingEntry._ID + "=?";
                selectionArgs = new String[] {
                        String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))
                };
                cursor = db.query(FeedingContract.FeedingEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection,
                        selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't find uri in PetProvider.query()");
        }
        Log.e("Gerke", "Cursor: " + DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));
        return cursor;
    }
```

The resulting error message is:

`"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase com.example.android.smartfeed.data.FeedingDbHelper.getReadableDatabase()'` on a null object reference"

My questions is: why is the global variable mDbHelper null and not an instance of my dbHelper?
Also tried saving the context to a global variable, but this also does not work.

Comment: Add log in onCreate just after `mDbHelper` to see whether it is initialized. Seems like it is not getting initialized or throwing some exception.

Comment: Hi, already did that, in onCreate() it is not null. With the debugger I can see, that in the onCreate method mDbHelper is defined correctly as an instance of my dbHelper. Even more interesting, according to Android Studio, when I am in the onCreate() method, the global mDbHelper is set to the helper, but when I am in query it is null again. So it seems like in between mDbHelper is set to null somewhen in between

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake:
The definition of the ContentProvider is fine, but when using it, I tried creating a new instance of it, which is wrong.

So for everyone else having my problem: 
The communication with the ContentProvider is done via the ContentResolver. To get an instance of the ContentResolver, call getContentResolver();